# How to remove this unexpected T_ELSE parse error

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using php and mysqli to be able to select and insert data into the database. The only problem I am having is that I am getting a parse error. This is when I am trying to do a fetch for the `$stmt` and then count the number of rows using the `$numrows` variable.

Can somebody help me and inform me what I need to do to remove the parse error?

I have pasted my code in this [fiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/sbFq7H)

Comment: For starters, don't be inconsistent in using brackets. In fact, always use them.

Comment: 121 line: change`else` -> `}else{`

Comment: And indenting; use it consistently and almost all these problems will disappear.

Comment: yeah, tabbing and using brackets for all if/else statements would make the code much easier to read and you'd probably be able to spot the issue right away.

Comment: This is proper book for you http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes when you try to use if ... else without proper nesting or missing one .

In your code at line 121 you called else which have no if.
close your if before this else.

```
**Line2** if ( (strlen($getemail) >= 7) && (strstr($getemail, "@")) && (strstr($getemail, ".")) )
         {
          //your cod
**Line 120** }
**Line 121**  else
          {
            $errormsg = "There is already a User with that Teacher ID"; 
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sure all your if-else brackets are closed.  It does not appear they are in this vase.  Like other commenters said, it is good to get in the practice of using brackets in all cases, not just using them around the if and not the else. That will lead to problems like this.  Also proper indenting will make it much easier to identify problems like these when you run into them.